# O que é Ajax e como usar?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Procurei exatamente o que é Ajax aqui no SO mas não encontrei, só encontrei como usar ajax pra isso e pra aquilo. Então queria entender melhor, porque eu só sei usar o JQuery, ja o Ajax eu só ouço/vejo o pessoal usando, mas não entendo muito. É alguma "parte" do JQuery?

Comment: Não sei porque dar _downvote_ numa pergunta válida (ainda que duplicada). Nem ela ser duplicada justificaria o voto, uma vez que o sistema de busca do chat não ajudaria alguém interessado em encontrar a pergunta original.